# Which protected variable used in inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose I have a Base class and its derived class Derived as follows:

```
class Base{
    private:
        _privateVar;

    protected:
        protectedVar;

    public:
        publicVar;

    void publicMethod(someValue, anotherValue)
    {
        protectedVar = someValue;
        publicVar = anotherValue;
    }
};

class Dervied: public Base{

    protected:
        protectedVar:
};

int main(void)
{
    Dervied d;
    d.publicMethod(valueA, valueB);
}
```

My question-

When I call `d.publicMethod(...)`, does the protectedVar in Derived get set or the one in Base class?

Thanks

--A

Comment: My question is: why would you override a protected variable?

Comment: @armundle A simple way to test is to run the program under debugger. Keep the break point at the assignment statement and test the address location of the variable being set with the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **When I call `d.publicMethod(...)`, does the `protectedVar` in Derived get set or the one in Base class?**

The method is a member of the Base class and hence it can access only the members of the Base class.

If the method belonged to your Derived class, then it would access Derived class member.
Because Derived class data members always hide Base class data members when accessed inside their own member functions.

Comment: The method is present in base class. What does your first statement meant ?

Comment: Will this change if I declare _publicMethod(..)_ as _virtual void_ in _Base_ class or do I need redefine this method in _Derived_ class so that the _Derived_ class _protectedVar_ is used?

Comment: @armundle: [Yes you need to make the method `virtual` in `Base` class and then override it in the `Derived` class](http://ideone.com/IPXI3).

Answer (score 5):

It is of `Base` class. Base class cannot access derived class members.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *override* a member variable, you can create another different variable in a different level in the hierarchy that has the same name, but they will be two unrelated variables. Within the context of the *use* of the variable, lookup will find one or the other and that is the one that will be picked up and used.

Polymorphism only applies to `virtual` member functions, not to non-virtual functions, not to member variables either.

Answer (score 0):

Since publicMethod is a methoc of the Base class, the protectedVar of the base class is set.

I don't know if this is what you want or expect, but even if this is what you want, I think it is not advised to do it like this.  Tools like PC-LINT will probably also warn you about such a construction.

Answer (score 0):

The member in the **base** class is modified.  Data members never behave as if they are virtual.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler reaches the definition of `Base::publicMethod`, it has to *statically* resolve all the names it uses.  At that point, the only possible resolution of those names are the members of `Base`, so the generated code will access those members.

Subclassing `Base` later on does not, and could not possibly, go back and change the code generated for `Base::publicMethod`.  The derived class could be in a different translation unit, or in a dynamically-loaded library.

---

If you want *dynamic* lookup, access `protectedVar` via a protected virtual accessor function: that would allow a derived class to interpose its own storage for the variable.

If `Base::protectedVar` and `Derived::protectedVar` have the same type anyway, it's hard to see what you expect to gain, but it would look like:

```
class Base
{
    Type protectedVarImpl;

protected:
    virtual Type & protectedVar();
    virtual Type const & protectedVar() const;

public:
    void publicMethod(someValue, anotherValue)
    {
        protectedVar() = someValue; // Note the method call
        publicVar = anotherValue;
    } 
};

Type& Base::protectedVar() { return protectedVarImpl; }
```